# How to use iptable to filter urls containing string?

Tags: iptables

to block all requests to  xxx.com :

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "xxx.com" --algo kmp -j DROP

What will block requests to any url containing xxx like ?

google.com?q=xxx&...

without blocking google.com.

Comment: I don't think you can do application-layer stuff with `iptables`. Even if you could, it would not work for https (which is encrypted). You probably want to install a filtering proxy (and you can use iptables to route to that).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [kpcre](https://github.com/xnsystems/kpcre), iptables PCRE extension.

For example, to filter the example you have pointed:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/\/.+xxx.+/i" --algo pcre -j DROP
```

The string "//.+xxx.+/i" denotes case insensitive strings which start with "/" and contain "xxx".

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested approach could potentially block dns requests, but if somebody uses the IP address directly that would be bypassed.

As suggested above you can use an http proxy.

Alternatively, I implemented a restriction of the type you mention without a proxy using dnsmasq and ipset. I list here the high level steps of how to do it:

1. create an empty ipset called myprohibitedsites
2. run your own instance of dnsmasq (you do not need the dhcp part of dnsmasq for this, just the dns cache)
3. configure all your machine to use your dnsmasq (or redirect udp port 53 to your dnsmasq via iptables)
4. configure your dnsmasq to log to the ipset myprohibitedsites all dns
   requests of the type xxx.com (see dnsmasq user guide)
5. configure iptables filter to drop all packets which have as destination the
   IPs contained in myprohibitedsites